# How to handle page refresh request for any URL of an SPA built using agularjs and hosted using S3 + Cloudfront?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have an SPA built using angularjs (version 1.5). I've hosted this application on S3 bucket. And have setup CloudFront in front of S3 bucket.

In order to make my application SEO friendly, I had to remove `#` from the URLs. I did this by enabling HTML5 mode. So, now my URLs don't have hash and everything works correctly through my hosted environment.

But, the moment I hit refresh (F5) for any url (except index.html), I see

```
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
```

Can someone please suggest how to handle page refresh, with my current setup?

With Cloudfront, I know, I can redirect 404 to say `index.html`. But, then any page refresh would redirect the user to index.html. This is not desired.

What I want to do is, when a user hits refresh, I want to re-render the same page, with refreshed contents.

Do I need to do URL Rewrite on S3, to achieve this? If yes, what should be my URL re-write rule?

Or, is there any better way with CloudFront to achieve this?

Comment: configure Error page for 404 and set index.html in CloudFront. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to define that all the urls in the app should render the `index.html` that runs your SPA.

I'm not sure how to do it with amazon, but with express it's just specifying an handler with `*` as a url (it sometimes calls "catch-all")